# Ajax Postback response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my script, i want to do an ajax post, and get the response and do an alert with it.

JavaScript Code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '../client_controller/teste',
   data: {form:$('#the-form-'+num).serialize(), key : num},
   success:function(response){
   alert(response); 
},
                                    },
});
```

And this is my example php code:

```
if($_POST['key']==1){
   parse_str($_POST['form'], $searcharray);
   $_SESSION['voo']=$searcharray;
   print_r( $_SESSION['voo']);
 }
```

It all works except when i alert the response, in the beginning it prints the response, but i also prints all my html and javascript page code.

Can anyone explain to me what im doing wrong and why this is happening?

Comment: Echo the content on a clean php page, with the content type header set to whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($_POST['key']==1){
   parse_str($_POST['form'], $searcharray);
   $_SESSION['voo']=$searcharray;
   print_r( $_SESSION['voo']);
exit();
 }
```

Comment: That exit() is hacks, but it shows up where is problem. Better is to split your code to view and ajax processing code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You have added an extra closing bracket in your code `},`

```
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '../client_controller/teste',
       data: {form:$('#the-form-'+num).serialize(), key : num},
       success:function(response){
                alert(response); 
            }                   
    });
```